# Is it possible to hide +Add Account button in Yodlee Fastlink?

Tags: css, yodlee

When the user adds a financial account using Yodlee Fastlink at the end of the wizard Fastlink allows to add more accounts (see on the attached picture below). Is it possible to remove or hide this button? Something like

```
#addOtherAccounts {
  display: none;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible once you become a customer. If you are already a customer then please get in touch with Yodlee support team: YI-Support@yodlee.com for the same.